# Class not found when I use another class from this namespace

Tags: php

I have index.php file and content in it(snip):

```
define('SMS_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/sms_ru_master/'); 
require_once(ENGINE_DIR . 'main/registry.php');
require_once(SMS_DIR . 'Api.php');
$registry = new Registry();
$sms = new \Zelenin\SmsRu\Api(new \Zelenin\SmsRu\Auth\ApiIdAuth($apiId));
$registry->sms = $sms;
```

I use Api.php to use API a bit of code:

```
<?php

namespace Zelenin\SmsRu;

use Zelenin\SmsRu\Auth\AuthInterface;
use Zelenin\SmsRu\Client\Client;
use Zelenin\SmsRu\Client\ClientInterface;
use Zelenin\SmsRu\Entity\AbstractSms;
use Zelenin\SmsRu\Entity\Sms;
use Zelenin\SmsRu\Entity\SmsPool;
use Zelenin\SmsRu\Entity\StoplistPhone;
use Zelenin\SmsRu\Exception\Exception;
use Zelenin\SmsRu\Response\AuthCheckResponse;
use Zelenin\SmsRu\Response\MyBalanceResponse;
use Zelenin\SmsRu\Response\MyLimitResponse;
use Zelenin\SmsRu\Response\MySendersResponse;
use Zelenin\SmsRu\Response\SmsCostResponse;
use Zelenin\SmsRu\Response\SmsResponse;
use Zelenin\SmsRu\Response\SmsStatusResponse;
use Zelenin\SmsRu\Response\StoplistAddResponse;
use Zelenin\SmsRu\Response\StoplistDelResponse;
use Zelenin\SmsRu\Response\StoplistGetResponse;

class Api
{
    /**
     * @var AuthInterface
     */
    private $auth;

    /**
     * @var ClientInterface
     */
    private $client;

    /**
     * @param AuthInterface $auth
     */
    public function __construct(AuthInterface $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
        $this->auth->setContext($this);
    }
```

But when I use

```
$sms = new \Zelenin\SmsRu\Api(new \Zelenin\SmsRu\Auth\ApiIdAuth($apiId));
```

I get error:  Fatal error: Class 'Zelenin\SmsRu\Auth\ApiIdAuth' not found in C:\OpenServer\domains\sowords.com\index.php on line 43

What should I do?

class on github https://github.com/zelenin/sms_ru

Comment: `use Zelenin\SmsRu\Auth\ApiIdAuth;` maybe?

Comment: No. It has AuthInterface which call classes.. I have a file called ApiIdAuth.php
and this is the file whish uses: namespace Zelenin\SmsRu\Auth;

Comment: `Interface` doesn't call classes, in fact `Interface` knows nothing about classes.

Comment: u're right it was my mistake.

I just don't know what to do. In documentation the way to auth is $sms = new \Zelenin\SmsRu\Api(new \Zelenin\SmsRu\Auth\ApiIdAuth($apiId));

But i cant understand what to do in this situiation..